# Power testing and a Poisson Distribution

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be a random sample from a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$.

If $X$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda$, then $\text{E}[X] = \text{Var}[X] = \lambda$; hence $\text{E}[X] = \lambda$ and $\text{Var}[X] = \lambda/n$.

(a) Test $H_0 :\lambda=4$ versus $H_A : \lambda>4$ and that our test procedure is to reject $H_0$ if $x \ge k$. Given $n = 100$, what value of $k$ gives a test with significance level approximately equal to $0.05$?

(b) What is the approximate power of the test at $\lambda = 5$?

Hi all, I'm new to this so any help is appreciated. For (a), I tried setting up a $95%$ confidence interval because I thought that $95%$ confidence and $5%$ significance were about the same.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: When you say x do you mean mean (x bar)

Comment: no, not the sample mean. X is a random variable with the characteristics stated above. I am seeking helping with power tests.

Comment: Oh I meant what do you mean by $x\geq k$ since you have 100 observations I don't know what x is

Comment: From my class notes I'm getting that I want to reject the simple null hypothesis if x, the random variable, is greater than or equal to k. How do I set up a test?

Comment: Thats my problem if I went out and got a sample of 100 from distribution what does rejecting if $x\geq k$ mean am it doesn't use all the observations in that statement I suspect it mean that sample average is greater than some value, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're asking now, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

So first to find test with significance level of at approximately 0.05 we see that we want
$$P_{\lambda\in\Theta_{Ho}}(\bar{X}\geq k)=P_{\lambda=4}\left(\sum X\geq 100k \right) = 1-P_{\lambda=4}\left(\sum X< 100k\right)=0.05$$
Where we see that $\sum X\sim \operatorname{Pois}(100\cdot4)=\operatorname{Pois}(400)$ Thus in order to find when this is true it can be a little tedious but you are going to have to calculate a list of possible $100k=t$'s and calculate $1-P(\sum X< t)$ (remember for $\operatorname{Pois}(400)$ and trying doing on excel) and see which is closest to $0.05$ (not above though). after you get $t^{*}$ that does this call it $t^{*}$ then $k=\frac{t^{*}}{100}$.

Now to calculate Power we just calculate 
$$\operatorname{power}(\lambda=5)=P_{\lambda=5}\left(\sum X\geq t^{*}\right) = 1-P_{\lambda=5}\left(\sum X< t^{*}\right)$$
where now $\sum X\sim \operatorname{Pois}(100\cdot5)=\operatorname{Pois}(500)$

also note $\sum X=\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i$

Also to your question about confidence interval, it is true you could calculate a $95\%$ confidence interval and that would correspond to $5\%$ significance level but the problem with trying to do this is that I don't really know what CI interval is for mean in poisson  and also even if you could derive it, CI intervals still rely on some critical value and since you can't really standardize or have table to look at for that it becomes situation above where you just have calculate probabilities for list of values and see which ones closets to significance level

Comment: I've never used excel to do calculations before, so could you help me with what I need to input? I entered poisson distribution with mean 4, x=100 and cumulative 0. My answer was 3.154 and I don't think that's right.

Comment: Ok so on excel when you have cumulative=TRUE that means it calculated Pr(X<=x) thus to get => you must subrtact that one from 1 then and Pr(X=x)

Comment: You can write $100\times4$ or $100\cdot4.$ Using an asterisk for that purpose is a workaround for occasions when you are limited to the symbols on the keyboard.